# using IE credentials to log on with c#

Tags: c#, webclient, credentials

Hi i am writing a HTML parser for helping with some job duties,
I can enter the site using IE explorer.
but using csharp code i get an error

i have tried using

```
client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
client.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

i don't get the requested page, but an error page.
if i can view page in explorer there must be a way to retrieve its html in C#

(note that same page in other browsers requires authintication - not in IE)

Comment: What is `client` - a WCF service client?

Comment: Who is running the IE when it works, and what do thier IE security settings say about automatic logon?

Comment: @Jodrell same user as the one running the C# application.

Comment: IE allows the currently logged on user to automatically authenticate with other MS services (assuming that they share the same domain/AD) - other browsers request the login details via a 403. Look at changing your .Credentials to use the NetworkCredential class. (`client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential('username','password');`

Comment: Hate to burst you bubble, but please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c and `HtmlAgilityPack` in particular.  If it can't do what you want (which I doubt) contribute a changeset.

Comment: @RichardSchneider i am not sure you understood my issue, the question you linked does not discuss authentication issue but parsing issue. i might of misunderstood you but it seems irrelevant to the question asked.

Comment: Read about `HtmlAgilityPack` it does most things well.  See http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: @james, your question is irrelecant. html agility pack does screen scraping and deals with authentication.  All the code is already there, why would you want to re-invent it.  You are just making your "job duties" harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the request header, C# sends no user-agnet header tag, 
and i guess the site i was trying to connect returns an error if encountered with no user agent.

added the following line to adjust header to my IE header :

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
client.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
```

Comment: Is `client` an instance of `WebClient`? We still don't know what you are doing ...

Comment: @jrummell you are correct, added code. client is webClient. i was getting an error page from server trying to connect with my C# code the above fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this library: https://github.com/HtmlUnit/NHtmlUnit

You can use html unit to programmatically perform html operations. Further info can be found at http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/30/using-htmlunit-on-net-for-headless-browser-automation/